# Simple way to exec same sql in diff database but same table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have eight databases: order0,order2... order7,
They all have  table 'orders' .
Now, I want exec sql like 'select * from orders where order_id = 652454122' in all eight databases.
I need to write sql like:

```
use order0
select * from orders where order_id = 652454122
use order1
select * from orders where order_id = 652454122
...
use order7
select * from orders where order_id = 652454122
```

Need copy seven times,it's Terrible!
Is there some simple way like:

```
use order0/order1/order2... 
select * from orders where order_id = 652454122
```

Comment: mysql sql sql-server - which?

Answer (score 2):

Create view that unions all 8 tables, something like:

```
CREATE VIEW vw_orders
AS
   SELECT *, 0 as DB FROM Order0..Orders
   UNION ALL
   SELECT *, 1 as DB FROM Order1..Orders
   UNION ALL
   ...
   SELECT *, 7 as DB FROM Order7..Orders
```

and then just select from it:

```
SELECT * FROM vw_orders WHERE order_id = 652454122
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following query to generate the 8 required queries-

```
select CONCAT(" select * from ",table_schema,".orders 
where order_id = 652454122;") from information_schema.tables 
where table_schema like 'order%' and table_name='orders'
```

You didn't need to write 8 query separately, use the above query and the result is the 8 query you need to write.